# How to read a dotted Gradle property in Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, properties, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I can read from `gradle.properties` with `val myProperty by settings`, and that's nice! But what if the property name contains dots? Consider the next `gradle.properties` file:

```
kotlin.incremental=true
kotlin.incremental.js=true
kotlin.incremental.multiplatform=true
```

How can I read those properties above in a `settings.gradle.kts` script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is what I found:

```
val myProperty: Boolean 
    get() = settings.extra["kotlin.incremental"]?.toString()?.toBoolean() ?: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the `extra` hack of your own answer, you can use

```
providers.gradleProperty("kotlin.incremental").get()
```

since Gradle 6.2.